# How can I read a XML file in PHP and generate a XML response?

Tags: php, xml

I´m a total newbie on PHP.

I´ve a XML file that I´ve to read, and then write as response to a PHP call.

```
<?php
$my_file = 'myfile.txt';

echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($my_file), ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

I tried that, but I guess the response is the xml content but encoded as html. 
How can I return a proper xml response?

### UPDATED: SOLVED

```
<?php
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r');
$sentinel = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$content = file_get_contents($stations);
echo $content;
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: pamelus, I did it, but in the wrong format :-) Now it´s fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending xml response when a url is hit in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471014/sending-xml-response-when-a-url-is-hit-in-php)

Comment: Is not the same. The other one talk about compose the content. This one was reading a XML file and putting the content as response.

Answer (score 1):

The question should not be how to generate XML response, but how to make the browser understand that the content of the response is XML.
To do so you should use the header function:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Which tells that the content of the response is indeed XML and not html.

Comment: thanks Dekel. Now you can see my code, where should I include the header?

Comment: Check the header function man page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php, you should put it before every output you have in your code.

Comment: when I read the file, as is a well formed XML, the header is included. So when I tried to include a new header, it crash.

Comment: Files don't contain headers. This is something that related to the HTTP protocol, so when you say crash - please be more specific - what exactly are you doing and what happen?

Comment: Thanks Dekel, the problem was use htmlspecialchars. You´re right with the header, so it´s solved now.